# Hybrid app crashing in Android studio with error: Session 'android': Error Launching activity

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a little new to Android Studio and hybrid application building suing cordova.

I am trying to build a Salesforce hybrid app in Android Studio.

The project gets cleaned and builds successfully without any errors.

But, while installing the APK to emulator it gives an error that

```
Session 'android': Error Launching activity
```

In the Emulator it says:

```
Unfortunately, app has stopped
```

My stack trace is as below:

```
09-20 01:44:34.430 7462-9492/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:44:43.439 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Queue length for executor GrecoExecutor with 1 threads is now 8. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
09-20 01:45:17.627 7462-9492/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:46:01.058 7462-9492/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:46:29.330 7462-9492/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:46:47.516 7462-9492/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:46:47.846 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Queue length for executor GrecoExecutor with 1 threads is now 8. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
09-20 01:46:48.319 8337-9489/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@336e7b1
09-20 01:46:48.323 8337-8500/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 786434]: Error reading from input stream.
09-20 01:46:48.324 8337-8500/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, ignoring error from engine(3): com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.h: Error reading from input stream.
09-20 01:46:48.325 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Task c[startRecognition] took 318737ms, which is over the 300000ms threshold
09-20 01:46:48.406 8337-9490/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Hotword detection finished
09-20 01:46:48.408 8337-8500/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error at processing input stream
09-20 01:46:48.422 8337-8504/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Stopping hotword detection.
09-20 01:46:48.422 8337-8500/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                              com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error at processing input stream
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.search.core.hotword.l.bsw(HotwordRecognitionRunner.java:166)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.search.core.hotword.l$1.run(HotwordRecognitionRunner.java:138)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.l$1.run(GsaThreadFactory.java:99)
                                                                                               Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.api.io.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.aHz(Tee.java:474)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.k(Tee.java:301)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ad.read(Tee.java:503)
                                                                                                  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.z.run(MultipleReaderAudioSource.java:206)
09-20 01:46:48.545 8337-8337/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordWorker: #onError(false)
09-20 01:46:53.715 8337-9505/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@eae2893
09-20 01:46:53.718 7462-7783/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-20 01:46:53.726 7462-9507/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xf39c0000 ready to run
09-20 01:46:53.783 8337-9505/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@eae2893
09-20 01:46:53.788 8337-9508/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Starting hotword detection.
09-20 01:46:53.791 8337-8337/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordWorker: onReady
09-20 01:47:11.373 7724-7740/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null

                                                                --------- beginning of system
09-20 01:47:11.377 7724-7740/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                                        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
                                                                        at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                                        at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                                     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                                        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002) 
                                                                        at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                                        at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                                        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
09-20 01:47:11.378 7724-7740/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
                                                                      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                                          at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
                                                                          at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                                          at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                          at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                                       Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                          at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                          at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                                          at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031) 
                                                                          at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                                          at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                                          at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
09-20 01:47:11.378 7724-7740/system_process E/KernelWakelockReader: neither /proc/wakelocks nor /d/wakeup_sources exists
09-20 01:47:11.380 7724-7740/system_process W/BatteryStatsImpl: Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
09-20 01:47:11.786 8511-9509/com.google.android.gms D/DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService: User is not opted-in to Usage & Diagnostics or Lockbox.
09-20 01:47:16.711 8138-8148/com.google.process.gapps W/art: Suspending all threads took: 63.308ms
09-20 01:47:25.361 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:47:43.857 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:47:57.846 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:47:58.515 7724-7738/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
09-20 01:47:58.516 7724-7738/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
09-20 01:49:22.116 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:49:22.434 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Queue length for executor GrecoExecutor with 1 threads is now 8. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
09-20 01:49:40.171 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Queue length for executor GrecoExecutor with 1 threads is now 8. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
09-20 01:49:41.652 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:50:32.159 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:50:39.881 8337-9508/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.k(byte[], int, int) from Tee.java:240 waiters=3 for 153ms
09-20 01:50:41.561 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:51:02.907 7724-7737/system_process I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
09-20 01:51:07.672 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:51:07.775 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Queue length for executor GrecoExecutor with 1 threads is now 8. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
09-20 01:52:19.800 7462-9507/? W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
09-20 01:52:59.098 8511-9511/com.google.android.gms I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1474314776671 (log), 1474314776671 (data)
09-20 01:52:59.662 7724-7760/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0

                                                               [ 09-20 01:52:59.723  7724: 7760 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fe99733e500, tid 7760
09-20 01:52:59.802 1187-1187/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1187: eglCreateSyncKHR(1370): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-20 01:52:59.880 7462-7780/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf44c0000) throttle end: throttle time(11)
09-20 01:53:00.121 7724-7743/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=android.graphics.Bitmap com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.screenshotApplicationsInner(android.os.IBinder, int, int, int, boolean) from WindowManagerService.java:6223 waiters=0 for 440ms
09-20 01:53:00.181 7724-7760/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
09-20 01:53:00.197 8337-8500/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@eae2893
09-20 01:53:00.218 7724-7991/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(android.app.IApplicationThread, int, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.service.voice.IVoiceInteractionSession, com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractor, android.os.IBinder, java.lang.String, int, int, android.app.ProfilerInfo, android.app.IActivityManager$WaitResult, android.content.res.Configuration, android.os.Bundle, boolean, int, android.app.IActivityContainer, com.android.server.am.TaskRecord) from ActivityStackSupervisor.java:946 waiters=0 for 537ms
09-20 01:53:00.218 7724-7851/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(android.app.IApplicationThread, int, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.service.voice.IVoiceInteractionSession, com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractor, android.os.IBinder, java.lang.String, int, int, android.app.ProfilerInfo, android.app.IActivityManager$WaitResult, android.content.res.Configuration, android.os.Bundle, boolean, int, android.app.IActivityContainer, com.android.server.am.TaskRecord) from ActivityStackSupervisor.java:946 waiters=1 for 446ms
09-20 01:53:00.252 8337-8337/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/VelvetPresenter: Still observing while not the active client
09-20 01:53:00.265 8337-8337/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/VelvetPresenter: Still observing while not the active client
09-20 01:53:00.274 8337-9508/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Hotword detection finished
09-20 01:53:00.276 8337-8504/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Stopping hotword detection.
09-20 01:53:00.306 8337-9329/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/TRThreadPoolExecutor: Task c[startRecognition] took 366597ms, which is over the 300000ms threshold
09-20 01:53:00.494 7724-7734/system_process I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20628(1791KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(320KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 915us total 350.246ms
09-20 01:53:00.542 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27734(1016KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 9% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 1.383ms total 225.598ms
09-20 01:53:00.577 8094-8094/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/GEL: handleIntent(Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL (has extras) })
09-20 01:53:00.701 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/art: Verification of void com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.bloblobber.k.save() took 107.172ms
09-20 01:53:00.899 8511-9514/com.google.android.gms D/DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService: User is not opted-in to Usage & Diagnostics or Lockbox.
09-20 01:53:01.047 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/art: Verification of boolean com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.bloblobber.m.a(java.io.File, android.content.Context) took 136.969ms
09-20 01:53:01.327 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
09-20 01:53:01.701 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4689(892KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 11MB/11MB, paused 3.743ms total 355.853ms
09-20 01:53:01.939 8337-9388/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe06f61a0
09-20 01:53:01.991 8094-8094/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/Choreographer: Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-20 01:53:02.122 7820-7833/com.android.systemui I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 50589(1951KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 821us total 322.859ms
09-20 01:53:02.158 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4540(265KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(2MB) LOS objects, 30% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 5.075ms total 287.771ms
09-20 01:53:02.186 8337-9521/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Starting hotword detection.
09-20 01:53:02.190 8337-9522/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@5e96f99
09-20 01:53:02.296 8094-8353/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: em, destroying layer...
09-20 01:53:02.309 7462-7976/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-20 01:53:02.402 7462-9524/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xf39c0000 ready to run
09-20 01:53:02.442 8337-9522/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@5e96f99
09-20 01:53:02.536 1187-1187/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
09-20 01:53:02.563 8337-8337/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordWorker: onReady
09-20 01:53:02.699 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
09-20 01:53:02.700 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
09-20 01:53:03.297 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20524(1572KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 11MB/13MB, paused 5.204ms total 170.783ms
09-20 01:53:03.326 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/linker: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0xa0a
09-20 01:53:03.811 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
09-20 01:53:03.813 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
09-20 01:53:04.023 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2343(173KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 13MB/13MB, paused 14.298ms total 92.333ms
09-20 01:53:04.154 8337-8347/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9385(661KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 13MB/17MB, paused 2.174ms total 103.590ms
09-20 01:53:04.283 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/linker: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x91
09-20 01:53:04.283 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/linker: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0x174
09-20 01:53:04.292 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/JNIHelp: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 255 native methods...
09-20 01:53:05.042 8337-9517/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
09-20 01:53:06.078 8511-9539/com.google.android.gms D/DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService: User is not opted-in to Usage & Diagnostics or Lockbox.
09-20 01:53:06.442 7724-7739/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=android.content.ComponentName com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startService(android.app.IApplicationThread, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int) from ActivityManagerService.java:15676 waiters=0 for 120ms
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Move on to native , and ditch hybrid:)

Comment: bro that cannot be my solution!!

Comment: Truth be told I was joking. But in all honesty, the only viable, long term solution, is to avoid hybrid applications at all cost. There are million reasons for it, too many to fit in here. The reason why the wast majority of successful hybrid applications are getting re-build in native solutions every day. But I suppose this is of topic here.

Comment: @SlobodanAntonijević Thanks for pouring that information

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the error message

> Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.

For me, the reason was that I was targeting Android 24. Android 24 has a change that results in a `FileUreExposedException` being thrown when using a file:// URI instead of a content:// URI. For more details, see:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html

Unfortunately, the emulator swallowed this exception so it was a bit difficult to detect; it showed only the "Buffer overflow, no available space." message.

A simple workaround is to target Android 23.

Better solutions are described here:

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)