# After launching the application it gives some unknow error

Tags: android

I have an android application which runs fine on my another laptop but when I run at my laptop it gives error and it only runs when we connect to laptop. If I send .apk by email then it does not work.

Here is my buidl.gradle apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "realtracker.in.cresol.realtracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //Date and Calendar picker https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

    //For Camera and video


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.layer-net:step-indicator:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.sandrios.android:sandriosCamera:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="realtracker.in.cresol.realtracker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitle">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Signup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Dashboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Report"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Welcome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_medicine_Description"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Reminder"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Activity_Event_Description"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver android:name=".Util.Reminder"/>
        <receiver android:name=".Util.BootReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the error code.

```
e.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
04-01 15:27:19.422 2153-12482/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                               com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                                Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                   at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
04-01 15:27:19.422 2153-12482/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
04-01 15:27:19.430 2153-2153/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
```

Comment: Please give us the error code, more context..

Comment: possible duplicate? "A simple workaround is to target Android 23." http://stackoverflow.com/a/40465399/1257369 - does it work with a real device?

Comment: are you using a virtual device and has it an sdcard mounted?

Comment: It only works with real device when we connect with usb and run otherwise by sending .apk by mail it does not work

Comment: no i am using real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly u have to build apk.
in your android studio- Build > Build APK and build your apk
and open apk location and install it in your real devices, it will work.