# Google play example Error code: 393238

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

I'm following this sample for connect my application to the API of google.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

But when it passes by `setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);` get this error...

```
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException:
Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
```

### activity_connection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Connection">

    <!-- sign-in button -->
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- sign-out button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Connection.java

```
package es.asdasdasdasd.as;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;

/**
 * Created by adrianpolalcala on 5/4/17.
 */

public class Connection extends Activity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private boolean mExplicitSignOut = false;
    private boolean mInSignInFlow = false;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    final static String MY_ACHIEVEMEMENT_ID = "153893430787-n0l2d18sekhshkf4chvucgtlp5fhbv1e.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // your achievement ID here


    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is starting.  This is where most initialization
     * should go: calling {@link #setContentView(int)} to inflate the
     * activity's UI, using {@link #findViewById} to programmatically interact
     * with widgets in the UI, calling
     * {@link #managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)} to retrieve
     * cursors for data being displayed, etc.
     * <p>
     * <p>You can call {@link #finish} from within this function, in
     * which case onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest
     * of the activity lifecycle ({@link #onStart}, {@link #onResume},
     * {@link #onPause}, etc) executing.
     * <p>
     * <p><em>Derived classes must call through to the super class's
     * implementation of this method.  If they do not, an exception will be
     * thrown.</em></p>
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState If the activity is being re-initialized after
     *                           previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most
     *                           recently supplied in {@link #onSaveInstanceState}.  <b><i>Note: Otherwise it is null.</i></b>
     * @see #onStart
     * @see #onSaveInstanceState
     * @see #onRestoreInstanceState
     * @see #onPostCreate
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Create the Googe Api Client with access to the Play Game services
        //TODO is 'this' the activity? (YES IS THIS)
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // Drive API
                .build();
    }


    /**
     * Called after {@link #onCreate} &mdash; or after {@link #onRestart} when
     * the activity had been stopped, but is now again being displayed to the
     * user.  It will be followed by {@link #onResume}.
     * <p>
     * <p><em>Derived classes must call through to the super class's
     * implementation of this method.  If they do not, an exception will be
     * thrown.</em></p>
     *
     * @see #onCreate
     * @see #onStop
     * @see #onResume
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mInSignInFlow && !mExplicitSignOut) {
            // auto sign in
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when you are no longer visible to the user.  You will next
     * receive either {@link #onRestart}, {@link #onDestroy}, or nothing,
     * depending on later user activity.
     * <p>
     * <p><em>Derived classes must call through to the super class's
     * implementation of this method.  If they do not, an exception will be
     * thrown.</em></p>
     *
     * @see #onRestart
     * @see #onResume
     * @see #onSaveInstanceState
     * @see #onDestroy
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        // The player is signed in. Hide the sign-in button and allow the
        // player to proceed.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // Attempt to reconnect
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // already resolving
            return;
        }

        // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow
        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
            mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                    mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }

        // Put code here to display the sign-in button
    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode
     * you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional
     * data from it.  The <var>resultCode</var> will be
     * {@link #RESULT_CANCELED} if the activity explicitly returned that,
     * didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.
     * <p>
     * <p>You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your
     * activity is re-starting.
     * <p>
     * <p>This method is never invoked if your activity sets
     *  to
     * <code>true</code>.
     *
     * @param requestCode The integer request code originally supplied to
     *                    startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this
     *                    result came from.
     * @param resultCode  The integer result code returned by the child activity
     *                    through its setResult().
     * @param data        An Intent, which can return result data to the caller
     *                    (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
     * @see #startActivityForResult
     * @see #createPendingResult
     * @see #setResult(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
                // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
                // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
                // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                        requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
        }
    }

    // Call when the sign-in button is clicked
    private void signInClicked() {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    // Call when the sign-out button is clicked
    private void signOutclicked() {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // sign out.
            mSignInClicked = false;
            Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);

            // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mExplicitSignOut = true;
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

### ErrorProcessor

```
05-09 19:59:36.421 2132-5956/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)

                                                                                              com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                               Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                                  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                                  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

### EDIT

return this error:

```
05-13 21:27:36.615 4501-5290/? E/ClientConnectionOperation: Handling ConnectionFailedException
                                                            mjs: Unable to resolve account name.
                                                                at mjr.a(:com.google.android.gms:7377)
                                                                at jil.run(:com.google.android.gms:189)
                                                                at llt.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                at lqc.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-13 21:27:36.715 4501-16392/? E/ValidateServiceOp: Using Google Play games services requires a metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of the manifest for es.iesnervion.qa
05-13 21:27:36.735 16368-16368/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: es.iesnervion.qa, PID: 16368
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: You may refer with this [related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590973/hybrid-app-crashing-in-android-studio-with-error-session-android-error-launc). One workaround is to lower your target to Android 23. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, you have to use [`FileProvider`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/5832311) class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.

Comment: so for use Google API my application can't be used for android 5.0? Android 5.0 is a indispensable requirements... :/

Comment: @AdriánPol do not mix with targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion,

Comment: Okay true, understood :). thank you and sorry for the failure :)

Comment: Please @abielita post your solution for close the question :) after, i would like comment your answer with the solution of the second trace error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590973/hybrid-app-crashing-in-android-studio-with-error-session-android-error-launc). One workaround is to lower your target to Android 23. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, you have to use [`FileProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/5832311) class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.

Comment: Thank you for your help abielita!!! :) for fix the second trace we only go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android :)