# android app stopped running on emulator and real device

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I am search for the reason why my app is not running on emulator (after apk build) and real device. It runs when I am in debug mode.

I have the logcat here, which is a long file, can anyone have a look and see what I miss?

Here is the file: [logcat file](http://pasted.co/5ac0e15c)

Answer (score 0):

Read through the logCat. Seems this is the caused of the error.

```
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error 
code: 393238
```

Check this out and see if it helps. [related Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900539/google-play-example-error-code-393238)

Comment: After digging, I found out, it had multiple causes. Signing of the app and which min level of SDK it allowed. After changing both, it works.