# Finding the cause of React Native Android App Crash

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

After spending many hours of tracing, I am unable to find the issue for the crash of React Native Android App. A white screen appears after react-native run-android and then suddenly the message displays MyApp has stopped! The App was previously working fine! Maybe the Android Studio updates have caused the issue! After doing adb logcat, here is the output! (Sorry for the detailed output).

```
12-10 09:10:00.586  1413  1413 I boot-pipe: done populating /dev/random
12-10 09:10:04.801  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
12-10 09:10:04.801  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
12-10 09:10:04.802  2603  2603 I AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
12-10 09:10:04.803  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
12-10 09:10:04.806  2603  2716 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
12-10 09:10:04.806  2603  2680 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@427c2af
12-10 09:10:04.806  1499  1594 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=10032 pid=2603
12-10 09:10:04.806  1499  1594 E         : Request requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
12-10 09:10:04.806  1499  1594 E         : android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD
12-10 09:10:04.806  2603  2680 E AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 281, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
12-10 09:10:04.807  2603  2680 E AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
12-10 09:10:04.807  2603  2680 E android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
12-10 09:10:04.807  2603  2680 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@427c2af
12-10 09:10:04.812  2603  2680 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@427c2af
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2908 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 W ErrorProcessor:    ... 11 more
12-10 09:10:04.813  2603  2716 I AudioController: internalShutdown
12-10 09:10:04.814  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
12-10 09:10:04.838  2603  2603 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
12-10 09:10:04.838  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
12-10 09:10:04.839  2603  2721 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
12-10 09:10:04.807  2603  2680 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
12-10 09:10:08.228  1626  1643 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
12-10 09:10:29.990  2603  2716 I AudioController: internalShutdown
12-10 09:10:30.005  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
12-10 09:10:30.005  2603  2603 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
12-10 09:10:30.005  2603  2603 I MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
12-10 09:10:30.005  2603  2721 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
12-10 09:10:30.581  4961  4961 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-10 09:10:30.588  4961  4961 W app_process: Could not reserve sentinel fault page
12-10 09:10:30.767  4961  4961 W app_process: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-10 09:10:30.769  4961  4961 I app_process: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
12-10 09:10:30.806  4961  4961 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-10 09:10:30.812  4973  4973 E asset   : setgid: Operation not permitted
12-10 09:10:31.343  1626  1652 W PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /data/app/vmdl1727045792.tmp/base.apk Binary XML file line #18
12-10 09:10:31.357  1626  1652 I PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dexoptNeeded=1) on: /data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/base.apk pkg=com.myapp isa=x86 dexoptFlags=boot_complete,debuggable,public target-filter=quicken oatDir=/data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/oat sharedLibraries=PCL[]
12-10 09:10:31.369  4976  4976 W dex2oat : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-10 09:10:31.369  4976  4976 W dex2oat : Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: -ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-popcnt) for the command line:
12-10 09:10:31.369  4976  4976 W dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=8 --zip-location=base.apk --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --oat-fd=9 --oat-location=/data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=quicken --swap-fd=11 --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
12-10 09:10:31.369  4976  4976 I dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --compiler-filter=quicken --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
12-10 09:10:31.371  4976  4976 W dex2oat : Could not reserve sentinel fault page
12-10 09:10:32.007  4976  4976 I dex2oat : dex2oat took 638.634ms (964.409ms cpu) (threads: 2) arena alloc=62KB (63776B) java alloc=4MB (5018336B) native alloc=5MB (5892024B) free=2MB (3020872B)
12-10 09:10:32.011  1626  1640 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.myapp appid=10080 user=-1: installPackageLI
12-10 09:10:32.162  1502  2099 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1727045792.tmp: No such file or directory
12-10 09:10:32.162  1502  2099 E installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1727045792.tmp: No such file or directory
12-10 09:10:32.163  1626  1652 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.myapp appid=10080 user=0: pkg removed
12-10 09:10:32.163  4961  4961 I Pm      : Package com.myapp installed in 1355 ms
12-10 09:10:32.179  4961  4961 I app_process: System.exit called, status: 0
12-10 09:10:32.179  4961  4961 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
12-10 09:10:32.184  1626  1683 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
12-10 09:10:32.188  1626  1683 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) InputReader identical 1 line
12-10 09:10:32.192  1626  1683 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
12-10 09:10:32.206  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.214  2691  2691 I chatty  : uid=10024(com.android.vending) identical 3 lines
12-10 09:10:32.215  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.221  2117  4693 E NetworkScheduler.SR: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
12-10 09:10:32.235  1626  2293 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.googlequicksearchbox.GelStubAppWatcher
12-10 09:10:32.244  1827  1827 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
12-10 09:10:32.247  1626  1626 I Telecom : DefaultDialerCache: Refreshing default dialer for user 0: now com.google.android.dialer: DDC.oR@AKc
12-10 09:10:32.256  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.256  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.260  2691  3046 W WearSignatureVerifier: No package com.google.android.wearable.app.cn
12-10 09:10:32.261  2691  3046 I chatty  : uid=10024(com.android.vending) GAC_Executor[1] identical 2 lines
12-10 09:10:32.261  2691  3046 W WearSignatureVerifier: No package com.google.android.wearable.app.cn
12-10 09:10:32.267  2691  2691 I Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.utils.PermissionPolicies$PermissionPolicyService.onStartCommand(18): post-install permissions check for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:32.267  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.267  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.270  1827  1827 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
12-10 09:10:32.273  2691  2691 I Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.externalreferrer.d.run(9): Package state data is missing for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:32.274  2117  2117 I WearableService: Wearable Services not starting - Wear is not available on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.281  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.bx(1166): No account configured on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.294  1827  1827 D ImsResolver: maybeAddedImsService, packageName: com.myapp
12-10 09:10:32.294  1827  1827 D CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0
12-10 09:10:32.298  2205  2215 I zygote  : Background concurrent copying GC freed 6722(457KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(520KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 68us total 112.528ms
12-10 09:10:32.301  2117  2380 D WearableService: onGetService - Wear is not available on this device.
12-10 09:10:32.302  2691  2691 W WearSignatureVerifier: No package com.google.android.wearable.app.cn
12-10 09:10:32.302  2691  2691 E Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-10 09:10:32.302  2691  2691 W Finsky  : [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.aj.run(9): Dropping command=auto_install due to Gms not connected
12-10 09:10:32.311  1626  1636 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.googlequicksearchbox.GelStubAppWatcher
12-10 09:10:32.312  1626  1640 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.account.full.FetchAccountPropertiesAppUpgradeBroadcastReceiver
12-10 09:10:32.312  1626  1640 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.backgroundsignin.BackgroundSignInBroadcastReceiver
12-10 09:10:32.312  1626  1640 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.experiments.phenotype.full.PhenotypeAppUpgradeBroadcastReceiver
12-10 09:10:32.312  1626  1640 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.notificationchannels.AppUpdateBroadcastReceiver
12-10 09:10:32.324  2368  4992 D Wear_Controller: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.myapp
12-10 09:10:32.350  1626  1636 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.googlequicksearchbox.GelStubAppWatcher
12-10 09:10:32.396  1743  1762 I zygote  : Background concurrent copying GC freed 13156(654KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/9MB, paused 64us total 201.135ms
12-10 09:10:32.419  2368  4999 D Wear_Controller: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.myapp
12-10 09:10:32.715  1626  2163 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5010:com.myapp/u0a80 for activity com.myapp/.MainActivity
12-10 09:10:32.732  5010  5010 W zygote  : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-10 09:10:32.735  1405  1444 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
12-10 09:10:32.758  5010  5017 E zygote  : Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-10 09:10:32.758  5010  5017 I zygote  : Debugger is no longer active
12-10 09:10:32.848  5010  5010 D FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
12-10 09:10:32.849  5010  5010 D FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
12-10 09:10:32.849  5010  5010 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
12-10 09:10:33.071  5010  5010 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
12-10 09:10:33.072  5010  5010 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: starting syncer worker
12-10 09:10:33.081  5010  5028 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
12-10 09:10:33.081  5010  5028 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-10 09:10:33.081  5010  5028 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
12-10 09:10:33.081  5010  5028 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.myapp
12-10 09:10:33.195  5010  5028 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11580470
12-10 09:10:33.224  5010  5010 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
12-10 09:10:33.224  5010  5010 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
12-10 09:10:33.241  1418  1431 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-10 09:10:33.496  5010  5010 E unknown:ReactNative: Unable to display loading message because react activity isn't available
12-10 09:10:33.513  1626  1647 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.myapp/.MainActivity: +807ms
12-10 09:10:33.537  5010  5028 I FA      : This instance being marked as an uploader
12-10 09:10:33.581  2368  2860 I Icing   : Indexing 0FC5A07B286EB89ECAB4195EE20B9EE1AB615B80 from com.google.android.gms
12-10 09:10:33.608  1418  1418 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
12-10 09:10:33.651  2368  2860 I Icing   : Indexing done 0FC5A07B286EB89ECAB4195EE20B9EE1AB615B80
12-10 09:10:33.686  5010  5028 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11580470
12-10 09:10:33.713  2603  2603 W SearchService: Abort, client detached.
12-10 09:10:33.839  2117  2117 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=null]
12-10 09:10:33.843  2117  5046 I Places  : ?: Couldn't find platform key file.
12-10 09:10:33.866  2117  2117 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=null]
12-10 09:10:33.868  2117  2117 I chatty  : uid=10014 com.google.android.gms.persistent identical 1 line
12-10 09:10:33.870  2117  2117 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=null]
12-10 09:10:34.484  5010  5015 I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=37KB
12-10 09:10:34.484  5010  5015 I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=36KB
12-10 09:10:34.484  5010  5015 I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
12-10 09:10:34.585  5010  5010 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
12-10 09:10:34.585  5010  5010 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
12-10 09:10:34.585  5010  5010 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
12-10 09:10:34.592  5010  5048 I zygote  : Thread[24,tid=5048,Native,Thread*=0x91290c00,peer=0x12d81bd8,"Thread-3"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
12-10 09:10:34.592  5010  5048 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
12-10 09:10:34.596  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
12-10 09:10:34.597  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
12-10 09:10:34.598  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
12-10 09:10:34.598  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
12-10 09:10:34.599  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
12-10 09:10:34.599  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
12-10 09:10:34.600  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
12-10 09:10:34.604  5010  5048 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
12-10 09:10:35.170  5010  5052 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11580470
12-10 09:10:35.479  1626  1636 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity (has extras)} from uid 10080
12-10 09:10:35.541  1405  1444 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
12-10 09:10:35.571  5010  5010 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp, PID: 5010
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/base.apk)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
12-10 09:10:35.576  5010  5010 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 E ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 E ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk
12-10 09:10:35.600  1743  1775 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 E ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 E ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W asset   : Asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 E ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.myapp-Sr-m6BJSCDuUztbtfBYRoA==/base.apk
12-10 09:10:35.601  1743  1775 W PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.myapp
12-10 09:10:35.603  1626  2291 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity
12-10 09:10:35.607  1626  1641 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.myapp u0
12-10 09:10:35.653  1405  1444 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3100672
12-10 09:10:35.658  1405  1444 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3100672
12-10 09:10:35.660  1405  1405 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3100672
12-10 09:10:35.671  1626  4828 I zygote  : android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
12-10 09:10:35.671  1626  4828 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-10 09:10:35.671  1626  4828 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-10 09:10:35.671  1626  4828 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-10 09:10:35.671  1626  4828 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
12-10 09:10:35.673  1626  4828 D EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x8c1a13e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
12-10 09:10:35.675  1626  4828 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8c1a13e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x91222030)
12-10 09:10:36.106  1626  1640 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1d73abc u0 com.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity t9 f}
```

The App is not using any microphone, strange there are some errors of Audio and Microphone. Here are the build details:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.0.8"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

I am using react-native: 0.53.0, with react-native-navigation: 1.1.375

**UPDATE**
I am finally able to run the app by replacing the android folder with one of earlier backups! Didn't exactly found out the issue, but it was something related to React Native Navigation. Here is the code snippet from the updated gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.0.9"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running the app on Emulator? How about on a real device?

Comment: Maybe you want to check out this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465399/4311268.

Comment: @RahulShukla already tried on real device. It crashes :-(. I am unable to locate the cause!

Comment: @TommyLeong okay will look out for this as well!

Comment: Usually in projects that I worked on it's best practise to have target and compile sdk version the same to avoid any unwanted bugs. Also what version are you buildTools ?

Comment: I think I had something similar. 1. Try uninstall app then build again 2. clean build folder 3. restart bundler/packager 4. close debugger in browser if running

Answer (score 0):

Can you try cleaning your android project and try building again after?

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

The error that crashes the app is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.myapp-uNSnIgB5mPdTGWEHkrTdCQ==/base.apk)
```

Generally, `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` should match, and the `buildToolsVersion` should also be of the appropriate version.

Try following the steps listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getfontlandroid-content-contexti).

Answer (score 0):

Well have you checked your package name **(eg: com.example.app)** matches with folder structure in your **android/app/main/java/com/example/app/(MainActivity and MainApplication)**. Like this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an issue with your `buildToolsVersion`. 
can you check that you have exactly the same versions as here?

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
```

Extracted from:
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.53.0&to=0.61.5